# JQuery: Disabling top menu for sliding tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I getting closer to my goal. But I am having difficulties in disabling the top menu for sliding tabs. My goal is that the user will only navigate the tabs through Previous/Next controls.  Some how my code is still not disabling the top menu. Any suggestion why? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PS336/102/)

Thanks

****JQUERY***

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.prev-tab').click(function() {
                    $('.st_tab_active').attr({'disabled': true});
               var tab=  $('.st_tab_active').parent().prev().children('a');
               tab.removeAttr('disabled');
               tab.trigger('click');
                return false;
                });

               $('.next-tab').click(function() {
                   $('.st_tab_active').attr({'disabled': true});
               var tab=  $('.st_tab_active').parent().next().children('a');
                tab.removeAttr('disabled');
                tab.trigger('click');
                return false;
            });

         });
  </script>
```

Comment: you want to do nothing if user clicks on tabs? ans change tabs using prev/next only?

Comment: @sabithpocker Yes that is correct

Comment: The plugin should be binding a click event on the tabs, you can unbind it. But then you cannot use tab.trigger('click') as tab has no bound click event now. Instead you will have to directly call plugin method.

Comment: +1 your comment, Can you show me this in jsfiddle or if you can post the full answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Please check the fiddle, i had a connection prob, so the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin looks like having an external linking feature

Check it here http://codecanyon.net/item/sliding-tabs-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/141774

Make next as an external link with href="#tab_2"

```
<a href="#tab_2">Next</a>
<a href="#tab_1">Prev</a>
```

When user clicks next it moves to tab_2 and updates link of next to #tab_3 and link of prev to #tab_1

It will need change in HTML/CSS and JS

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/PS336/104/

Comment: +1 Wow very nice. But I need something at the bottom of the tabs that has a previous/next for the user to click.

Comment: @jonthecoder2346 Can you explain that? This already has prev/next right now at left and right of the tabs.

Comment: Yes, it has the previous and next at the top left and right. But can i have another set show at the bottom of the tab content with the words Next/Previous.

Comment: yes in this format <a href="#tab_1" class="st_ext prev" rel="st_horizontal" > </a> change the prev class to some other or override those css. If you change the class to say. inline-prev, add that selector also to the jQuery click binding

Comment: Ok, You have gotten me super close. So i have this <a href="#tab_2" class="st_ext next" rel="st_horizontal" >Next</a> and it works fine. but the previous is not:  <a href="#tab_1" class="st_ext prev" rel="st_horizontal" >Previous</a>. Take a look in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PS336/106/).